# Setting font size property for FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I am trying to set data template for listbox in code behind using FrameworkElementFactory, I have a checkbox in a data template and i just need to set the font size of the checkbox.

Here is the code.

```
FrameworkElementFactory Name = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
Name.SetBinding(CheckBox.ContentProperty, new Binding("Content"));
Name.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("BooleanValue"));
Name.SetValue(CheckBox.FontSizeProperty, 20);
stackpnl.AppendChild(columnName);
```

In this code I couldn't able to set the FontSizeProperty.

Exception arises showing the message that **20** is not the valid value for font size.

Please correct this code, if something went wrong here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FontSize` is of a `double` type so your value must be passed as `double` to be unboxed properly. Try this:

```
Name.SetValue(CheckBox.FontSizeProperty, 20D);
```

Comment: Tried the way you suggested, it is not throwing exception, but font size remains unchanged, am I doing it wrong? :(

Comment: For me it sets `FontSize` fine. How do you use this `FrameworkElementFactory`? Do you see `CheckBox` which is otherwise fine, with expected `Content` and `IsChecked` value?

Comment: Yea it is working fine with other properties.. but struck in FontSize

Comment: Do you change template for `CheckBox`? I've created simple `DataTemplate` using your code and it sets all 3 properties fine in my case

Comment: No, I didn't change anything, even tried with heightproperty and widthproperty. Everything is good except this.

Comment: The problem is not in this code. Something else must be forcing `FontSize`. This code works

Comment: Hi, I have checked with the other simple sample, works fine. problem is some where in my code, thanks for response